# C program with two dimensional arrays?

Tags: c

in a two dimensional array there are kept the working hours for N workers and M projects,the names of the workers are kept in an array with the name Worker and the name of the projects in an array with the name "Project".Write a program which reads the data and displays the worker with more working hours.So I tried this,but everytime I ran it,it seems to be a logical error,because it says :Give the number of the project,and If I type "2" this is also the number of the workers according to my program,and then it asks for the hours for each worker..

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j, n, worker[100][10], hours[30][100];

    printf("The number of the project: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("Give the worker %d: ", i+1);
        scanf("%s", &worker[i]);
    }

    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("\n The worker  %s\n", worker[i]);
        for (j=0; j<30; j++)
        {
            printf("The number of the hours for the day %d: ", j+1);
            scanf("%d", &hours[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<30; j++)
            if (hours[i][j]==0)
                break;
        if (j==30)
            printf("%s\n", worker[i]);
    }

    getch();
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: And the question is ?

Comment: Solve my homework?

Comment: Dont be rude to me.I have worked very much on this...I work on C 3 hours everyday and sometimes I dont understand what is going on..

Comment: I didn't mean to be rude, but it looks like you already got the answer on [Yahoo! Answers](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index;_ylt=ArPAc2C8ztnTfYKYWzbJSpRyaxV.;_ylv=3?qid=20130510072927AAbwpBY). The people answering here have lives too and probably don't want to waste time answering questions already answered elsewhere.

Comment: They both answered wrong ...

Comment: Vague title is unlikely to be useful to future visitors to the site who may have the same problem as you. Actually, it's unlikely that any future visitors will have this same problem.

Comment: I re-edited it Raymond..

Comment: You also forgot to ask a question. Is your problem with the scanf of the worker name?

Comment: Thats the point,I dont know what have I done wrong..

Comment: One problem is that you have arrays of integers but your trying to store strings in them; this is not going to work.  For example, you're trying to use `"%s"` to read into `int worker[100][10];`; this is a type mismatch that a good compiler will report to you (if invoked with the right options).  Since the headers include `<conio.h>`, you may or may not get such warnings easily.  However, this is one of the bugs in the code.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be taking the input incorrectly.

```
scanf("%s", &worker[i]);
```

`worker` is a 2D array of type **int**. So, you need to have another index while taking input. Also the format specifier for **int** is `%d`. Any decent compiler should have given you warnings during compilation.

Comment: I think he intends for 'worker' to be an array of strings, containing the names of each of the workers.

Comment: @jarmod I too thought the same. But for `hours` also OP has a 2D array.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you first must ask how many workers (N) and how many projects (M) with something like:

```
int ii, m, n;
char **worker;
char **project;

printf("How many workers? ");
scanf("%d", &n);

printf("How many projects? ");
scanf("%d", &m);
```

Then ask for the names of the workers:

```
// Allocate space for n worker string pointers
worker = (char **)malloc(n * sizeof(char *));

for (ii = 0; ii < n; ++ii)
{
  char bufname[1024]; // danger here if input too long
  printf("Name of worker[%d]? ", ii + 1);
  scanf("%s", bufname);
  worker[ii] = strdup(bufname);
}
```

Then ask for the names of the projects, similarly.  Then get the hours, then calculate the max, then free up the dynamically allocated worker & project strings (and the two array of pointers).